# El Capitan SIP and CPAN

Tags: macos, perl, sip

As we know, Apple introduced it's new "rootless" feature in El Capitan that greatly restricts what the root user is capable of doing.  Unfortunately this feature breaks CPAN for Perl users.  One can install new CPAN modules but you cannot install a new version of CPAN — because that goes into `/usr/bin/`.  I know I can disable [SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) but I'd prefer to work with it for a while.

Anyone know a solution to the CPAN problem?

Comment: If you're not willing to, temporarily, disable SIP then install to `/usr/local/bin` as that's not protected by SIP.

Comment: Consider isolating `perl` and your CPAN modules from Apple with [perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl) – see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/198575/how-best-to-isolate-my-development-environment-on-os-x/198620#198620

Answer (score 4):

You can install a newer version of `cpan` in `/usr/local/bin` with the following CPAN configuration:

```
cpan
cpan> o conf makepl_arg "INSTALLBIN=/usr/local/bin INSTALLSCRIPT=/usr/local/bin"
cpan> o conf commit
cpan> exit
sudo cpan -i CPAN
```

This solution, and others, is discussed at [perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl/perlop.html?node_id=1144316).